# How to share Typescript Types between Projects?

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have two projects (client and server) that should share the same definitions. To achieve this i outsourced my definition (`.d.ts`) in an extra npm package that I linked back to both projects via `npm link`. The types in the new npm package are not recognized by the two main projects. I tried `package.json` (`types`) settings and some settings in `tsconfig.json` (`types`, `typeRoot`) in various combinations, but I didn't get the right one.

What I have to set up in the definition package and the main packages to get that working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`types` and `typeRoots` didn't work for me and I try many different paths/combinations (especially in `typeRoots`).

Finally I added the line

```
"include": [
    ...,
    "node_modules/<my-npm-package>/*.ts"
],
```

in tsconfig.json and my outsourced typings are available in the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't give enough information to deduct what is going wrong. First of all, if you use `index.d.ts` inside node_moudels, and put in the root of your npm package, typescript should automatically use types from the package, no extra setup needed.

However, you use `index.d.ts` file only if you type JavaScript code (compiled code). If you just want to share types, you use `index.ts` and then include the path to the folder where shared type is inside `"typeRoots"`.

Comment: Thank you for the try. I found the solution that worked for me (see my answer)